# mySQL query optimisation — multiple joins or select … where not in (select distinct…)?

Tags: mysql, join, performance, subquery, query-performance

### Background

I have a Drupal install accessing a large users database (~200k rows) and my "People finder" functionality needs to access all those rows (in a random order). I don't seem to be able to use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` from within Drupal's UI (and I have a slightly different Drupal-specific question on Drupal.SE at [Slow query with large dataset in Drupal views — better to process in SQL or PHP?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/26874/3966), which addresses that issue, as well as parts of this one), **but my mySQL-specific question is as follows**:

I need to exclude some rows based on data in another table ("include all users in rôle A who are not also in rôles B, C or D). The query Drupal is generating is effectively

```sql
SELECT
    users.uid AS uid,
    /* some columns */,
    RAND() AS random_field
FROM
    users users
    INNER JOIN users_roles users_roles ON users.uid = users_roles.uid
    LEFT JOIN users_roles users_roles2
        ON users.uid = users_roles2.uid
        AND (users_roles2.rid = :views_join_condition_0
          OR users_roles2.rid = :views_join_condition_1
          OR users_roles2.rid = :views_join_condition_2)
WHERE
    (( (users.status <> :db_condition_placeholder_3)      -- Active users only
    AND (users_roles.rid = :db_condition_placeholder_4)   -- Must be in rôle A
    AND (users_roles2.rid IS NULL)                        -- Must not be in rôles B, C, D
    AND (users.uid != :users_uid OR users.uid IS NULL) )) -- Must not be current user
ORDER BY random_field ASC
```

(The reference to `users.uid IS NULL` is a red-herring; that should never be the case and is not germane to this query.)

### Question

Now it strikes me that hand-rolling Drupal's filter criterion (within the constraints of Drupal's UI) might help — and I can hard-code almost all the `:db_condition_placeholder`s — but I'm not sure if there's a significant performance difference between the following two options:

1. Change the `FROM` clause to

   ```sql
   FROM users INNER JOIN users_roles
       ON users.uid = users_roles.uid AND users_roles.rid NOT IN (6, 8, 9)
   ```

   (and then do the `WHERE users_roles.rid = 5` as before, just removing the `users_roles2` reference); or
2. Remove the `JOIN` altogether and change the `WHERE` clause to:

   ```sql
   WHERE users.status = 1                                             -- Active users only
       AND users.uid IN
          (SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM users_roles WHERE rid = 5)        -- Must be in rôle A
       AND users.uid NOT IN
          (SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM users_roles WHERE rid IN (6,8,9)) -- Not rôles B, C, D
       AND users.uid != :users_uid                                    -- Not current user
   ```

### Extra information

If it helps, the mySQL version number is `5.1.50-enterprise-gpl-pro`, all tables use the InnoDB storage engine and the table `users_roles` has a clustered primary key across the two columns already:

```sql
mysql> describe users_roles;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| uid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| rid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The actual performance problem I'm seeing is twofold — the server is maxing out on RAM and the query I'm discussing here takes over 2 seconds to execute. I'm guessing I can't address the RAM without looking at `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, but speeding up this query would definitely be a good start.

#### More extra info, as requested

```sql
mysql> describe users;
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| uid              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| name             | varchar(60)      | NO   | UNI |         |       |
| pass             | varchar(128)     | NO   |     |         |       |
| mail             | varchar(254)     | YES  | MUL |         |       |
| theme            | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |       |
| signature        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |       |
| signature_format | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| created          | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| access           | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| login            | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| status           | tinyint(4)       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| timezone         | varchar(32)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| language         | varchar(12)      | NO   |     |         |       |
| picture          | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| init             | varchar(254)     | YES  |     |         |       |
| data             | longblob         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT
    users.uid AS uid,
    /* some columns */,
    RAND() AS random_field
FROM
    users users
    INNER JOIN users_roles users_roles ON users.uid = users_roles.uid
    LEFT JOIN users_roles users_roles2
        ON users.uid = users_roles2.uid
        AND (users_roles2.rid = 6 OR users_roles2.rid = 8 OR users_roles2.rid = 9)
WHERE
    (( (users.status <> 0)                           -- Active users only
    AND (users_roles.rid = 5)                        -- Must be in rôle A
    AND (users_roles2.rid IS NULL)                   -- Not in rôles B, C, D
    AND (users.uid != 35635 OR users.uid IS NULL) )) -- Not (random valid UID)
ORDER BY random_field ASC
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                    | rows  | Extra                                                     |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users_roles  | ref    | PRIMARY,rid   | rid     | 4       | const                  | 69985 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users        | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | dbname.users_roles.uid |     1 | Using where                                               |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users_roles2 | ref    | PRIMARY,rid   | PRIMARY | 4       | dbname.users.uid       |     1 | Using where; Using index; Not exists                      |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: The performance issue is probably the `ORDER BY RAND()`.

Comment: I was literally just about to see what the impact was of removing that sort criterion. I'll report back ;o)

Comment: The change `AND users.uid IN (SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM users_roles WHERE rid = 5)` would probably make the query **less** efficient in current MySQL optimizer.

Comment: You should try running from PHPmyAdmin or Workbench or command line interface and add in your question the `EXPLAIN` output (what `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...` shows).

Comment: And you could add the 2 tables' definitions (what are the column datatypes and the existing indexes). For example, an index on `users_roles (rid, uid)` would probably help this query (in original or whatever version you rewrite.) If I understand correctly, there's only a `(uid, rid)` index.

Comment: With `ORDER BY RAND()`, it averages at 2390.17 milliseconds; without, it averages at 2251.48 milliseconds. Whilst 150ms aren't to be sniffed at, that's still not the primary problem with the query ;o)

Comment: @ypercube I've added the other table definition and the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT`, having pasted in real, valid values for the query argument placeholders. Also, a friend's Googling suggested a [covering index](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/tag/covering-index/) might help, but I don't yet know what those are  ;o)

Comment: Never do SELECT ... IN (SELECT) in MySQL.  MySQL does outside->in evaluation, so SELECT ... IN (SELECT) is O(n^2).

Comment: @Aaron: Actually `SELECT ... IN (SELECT ...)` can be fast if the external table is small. The plan is more like `O( Nexternal * log(Minternal) )`

Comment: @ypercube The external table is by no means small. `select count(*) from users;` gives me `190467` and `select count(*) from users_roles;` gives me `190494` — they're Drupal's means of identifying users and rôles.

Comment: @Owen: Yes, in your case, this is a no-no. No argue there. Until MySQL optimizer is improved (MariaDB latest release has some optimizer improvements, and `SELECT ... IN (SELECT )` is one of them. But I don't when (and if) these will be adopted by main-tree MySQL.)

Comment: @ypercube Fair enough. Changing database engine is most certainly not an option at this stage of the project, in any case. I'll take a look implementing at your suggestions below, anyway. Thanks again :o)

Comment: Everything is fast when the table is small :)

Comment: @AaronBrown Indeed  :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I would add an index on `users_roles (rid, uid)`. In a many-to-many table with two columns `(a,b)`, you almost always will need both indexes: `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` in one query or the other. I think this index would help in this query.
- Try various rewritings of the query and the `EXPLAIN EXTENDED` they produce.
- About your suggestions, the first is not correct (it will not show same results). For the second suggestion:

```
WHERE users.status = 1                                           -- Active users only
```

Yes, that's better than `users.status <> 0`. This change may have a better effect if there is an index on `users (status)` (and even more if there are not many active users). Optimizing queries with boolean columns (or ones that act as boolean) is not easy with B-trees.

```
  AND users.uid IN
     (SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM users_roles WHERE rid = 5)        -- Must be in rôle A
```

No. MySQL is known to have issues with `column IN (SELECT ...)`, especially if the external table is big (and yours is 200K columns, so no, not good).

```
  AND users.uid NOT IN
     (SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM users_roles WHERE rid IN (6,8,9)) -- Not rôles B, C, D
```

Yes, that is one way to rewrite. The `DISTINCT` is redundant though.

```
  AND users.uid <> :users_uid                                    -- Not current user
```

Yes, removing the `users.uid IS NOT NULL` may help and does not change the result.

- Other things you could try:

Moving the `rid = 5` condition to the `ON` clause:

```
INNER JOIN users_roles users_roles 
  ON  users.uid = users_roles.uid
  AND users_roles.rid = 5
```

The (rewrite) to `NOT IN` can also be written with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
  AND NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM users_roles ur 
        WHERE ur.uid = users.uid 
          AND ur.rid IN (6,8,9)
      )
```

Comment: Thank you; that looks very helpful. Almost all users will be active, frustratingly (as inactive users are far more likely to be in a specific rôle that has minimal site access instead). So it sounds like I want to add an index on `users (status)`, another on `users_roles (rid, uid)` move `rid=5` to the `ON` and use `NOT EXISTS` in that same `ON`. My computing theory is bad, so I don't really understand _O(n^2)_ vs _O(Nexternal * log(Minternal))_ but does that mean I'd be better off using three `AND` conditions instead of the `AND ur.rid IN...` condition?

Comment: @Owen: No, that comment was only releveant to the `SELECT ... IN (SELECT)` issue.

Comment: Cool, thanks. It's also been suggested (on Twitter) that `ORDER BY NULL` will stop it using a temp table on disc and remove the filesort. If I'm gonna mess with the SQL query, I guess I may as well append that and see if it helps ;o)

Comment: Indeed, `ORDER BY NULL` does indeed do that: "Using where; Using index" instead of "Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort"

Comment: With all of that, we've managed to halve the execution time. The query now reads: `SELECT /* columns */ FROM users INNER JOIN users_roles ON users.uid = users_roles.uid AND users_roles.rid = 5 WHERE (users.status = 1) AND (users.uid != :users_uid) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users_roles ur WHERE ur.uid = users.uid AND ur.rid IN (6,8,9)) ORDER BY NULL;`. Now I just need to persuade Drupal to let me use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` and it'll go from 1 second to 2 milliseconds. Not bad for something that was originally 1000× that! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Off course you know that `OFFSET` does not make sense without `ORDER BY`

Comment: Yes, indeed. We just haven't worked out what we're gonna `ORDER BY` yet  :o)